# Why can't dlls required for a Blazor web app not be properly preloaded in client computer?

Tags: blazor

Have read about two important Blazor problems, both related to .NET and app dlls. One is latency because the dlls have to be downloaded each time the web app is started and the other one is blockage of those same dlls by security software.

It would seem that both issues could be resolved if the browser was able to load dlls that had been previously properly installed in client. Why is this not possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Who said it's not? The libraries are *cached* so they don't have to be downloaded every time. If the application is built as a PWA it can even work offline. Blazor is no different than other SPAs in that respect

Comment: Thank you for your response Panagiotis, that wasn't clear to me at all. Would the cache remain for an application that is used only a few times a month?

Comment: As for latency, loading is slower but actually running the app is faster because like all SPAs, only the data is retrieved by the server, not the entire page